# Intellij IDEA 2016.1.3 and 2016.2 wrong rendering fonts on Ubuntu?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm on an Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.
I just installed Intellij IDEA 2016.1.3 and got disapointed from the way my usual fonts (Dialog - for dialog windows and Monospaced for editor) are displayed. They are like completely different fonts in this new version.

This is very frustrating and I had to downgrade the Intellij IDEA to my previous version (2016.1) where the fonts are displaying OK.

Anyone with the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the problem is in the JDK/JRE version with which Intellij Idea is started. When started with an oracle JRE it renders fine.
When started with the OpenJDK bundled with Idea version 2016.1 it again renders fine.
Lets hope they fix the bundled JDK in new Idea versions.

Just updated the JetBrains issue tracker:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160158

Comment: George is right and you can fix this for now by editing the idea.sh script to NOT look in the intellij folders for a jdk but instead go straight to the ones on the system, where you will have setup oracle jdk.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had this issue personally but it looks like it may be fixed in 2016.2
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2016.2+EAP

> IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2 162.74.16 General The installer for Windows now
>   comes with our custom JDK build where we address some issues with
>   focus and font rendering.

This says windows, so it may also not be it.

Comment: No, even the new 2016.2 official version does not render fonts well (unfortunately)